# Navigate to another page on button click

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone, blend

I am developed the Windows **mobile application** I've added the button for **VS blend 2015** , but there's no **button navigate to** option how to bind to my button for the page  **sub.xaml**

```
<Button x:Name="button" Content="Enter" Height="42" Margin="122,-113,0,0" 
     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="144" Foreground="#FF50CBC5" 
     Background="#FF0F0E0E" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

Comment: i want to navigate button for the sub.xaml page

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The hyperlink button gives you the option to navigate to another page onclick.

This screen shot is from Blend.

[image]

So change your mark up as follows, including the generated Click handler.

```
<HyperlinkButton x:Name="button" Click="HyperlinkButton_Click"
    Content="Enter" Height="42" Margin="122,-113,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="144" Foreground="#FF50CBC5" 
    Background="#FF0F0E0E" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

Then in your cs, you need to direct the navigation.

```
// Button to navigate to sub.xaml page.
private void HyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Navigate back to sub.xaml page.
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SubPage));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have a Click event for button. In that click event, write the code as

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {    
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/sub.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));   
    }
```

Comment: I am unable to use any of the above solutions in WPF, In WPF how to navigate?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using following steps.

**1st Step** - add a new button on your window and change the properties as you wish.

**2nd Step** - double click on that button. then you will go to the cs file like this.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    

}
```

**3rd Step** - create new object of window that you want to navigate and open that, then close current window

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    NewWindow newWindow = new NewWindow();
    newWindow.Show();
    this.Close();
}
```

Thanks.